# use vpn with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, vpn

I have to following problem. I need to check if certain urls are working and returning a correct response. I want to use python requests for this. However the urls have a redirect in it if the device or geo is incorrect and we need to check a lot of urls for mobile sites and multiple geo's.

Is there a way to work through a VPN with Python requests?

Edit:
I forgot to mention, this is for a ubuntu 14.04 server. So not a home pc. On my laptop I use HideMyAss and IpVanish but I want to run a cron job on my server to check it automatically. I don't need to hide any information so I can use a proxy as well.

Comment: Can't you just setup the VPN on your computer so that all your connections go through the VPN? This way your Python requests will also go through the VPN.

Comment: No, that did not work. I think the answer below is the right way to do it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on the OS you use, these options are available:

1. If OS X: use the Apple's Automator scripts to switch VPN connections (provided they are set up beforehand). You can use then a bash script which will wrap your python script and switch connections (based on URL, for example)
2. Use a list of proxies (not VPNs). This is the easiest solution
3. Use a custom VPN connection management, something like this: https://gist.github.com/domenkozar/1547663
   This option will require a lot of work though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to proxies instead of VPNs. This is indeed an option. However I don't find so many working http proxies and sock4/5 doesn't seem to be working. Is there a way to get sock4/5 working  with requests?

Comment: @user3605780 You can, but you have to update to latest version: `2.10.0`. Previous versions only accept http and https proxies.